# Find a Continuous and bijective function but not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Find a function $Y\rightarrow X$ that is continuous and bijective but not a homeomorphism.

How would I find one?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: The identity map from $\mathbb R$ with discrete topology to  $\mathbb R$ with usual topology.

Comment: You can also check out https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30661/non-homeomorphic-spaces-that-have-continuous-bijections-between-them

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f:[0,1)\rightarrow S^1$(here $S^1$denotes the unit circle in a complex plane) defined by the formula $f(t)=e^{2πit}$.It is easy to see that $f$ is a continuous bijection, but $f$ is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Would f:[0,2pie) -> S1. f(t)=(cos(t),sin(t)) be one as well. Sorry for the bad annotation

Comment: You can define by $f(t)=(cos2\pi t,sin2\pi t)$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial topology where the only open sets are $\phi$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f(x)=x$.

This function is trivially a bijection, and it is continuous because the reverse image of the two open sets are both open.

Comment: Or choose the discrete topology on $Y$ and the usual topology on $X$ instead, same map.